# ajax returns an error even if everything is ok

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I have this simple code

the data is regularly saved on the server but always generates the error "Error ListaSegnalazioni! undefined"

if I remove the instruction `e.preventDefault();` the error vanishes!

what could be the problem?

```js
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/api/PostListaSegnalazioni/',
          data: JSON.stringify(rows),
          "dataSrc": "",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            alert("Dati Inviati!");
          },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              alert("Error ListaSegnalazioni! " + xhr.responseText);
            }
          });
```

Comment: the problem is on the server side - the problem vanishes if you don't e.preventDefault probably because you're in a form submit handler, and the form submits instead of your code running

Comment: I would `console.log(status, error)` in the error handler instead to see what the error actually is

Comment: "}," is on code. i update the question. my transcription error probably.

Comment: We can't tell why the error handler is running based on what you've told us. You need to look at the `status` variable, look at the `error` variable, and look at the server side code.

Comment: error variable is empty, status variable report "error".

Comment: the same code, using on 'PUT' method work without error.

Answer (score 0):

***incredible!!*****

i modify the code and the error vanish!!

```
$.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: '/api/PostListaSegnalazioni/',
                                data: JSON.stringify(rows),
                                "dataSrc": "",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    alert("Dati Inviati!");
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText.includes("undefined"));
                                 if (xhr.responseText != "undefined") { alert("Error ListaSegnalazioni! " + xhr.responseText);}
                                }
                            });
```

it was enough to insert the instruction `alert(xhr.responseText.includes("undefined"));`

very but very strange behavior!!

Comment: Please look in the console. There is likely another issue that makes the form submit somehow. When an alert fixes a problem in an async communication with the server, then there is a timing or error issue

Comment: no errors in the console. the record is correctly sent to the server ...

Comment: What happens if you remove  `"dataSrc": "",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",`

Comment: for completeness, the first call ajax correctly sends but returns an undefined error that is ignored with the last changes. from the second call ajax on, everything happens regularly including the 'success' alert

Comment: What is  the reason for "dataSrc": "",  ? am just trying to remove unnecessary stuff

Comment: if I remember correctly, I had been suggested for compatibility with the 'datatables' tables.